# In Python, have json not escape a string

Tags: python, json

I am caching some JSON data, and in storage it is represented as a JSON-encode string. No work is performed on the JSON by the server before sending it to the client, other than collation of multiple cached objects, like this:

```
def get_cached_items():
  item1 = cache.get(1)
  item2 = cache.get(2)
  return json.dumps(item1=item1, item2=item2, msg="123")
```

There may be other items included with the return value, in this case represented by `msg="123"`.

The issue is that the cached items are double-escaped. It would behoove the library to allow a pass-through of the string without escaping it.

I have looked at the documentation for [json.dumps `default` argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage), as it seems to be the place where one would address this, and searched on google/SO but found no useful results.

It would be unfortunate, from a performance perspective, if I had to decode the JSON of each cached items to send it to the browser. It would be unfortunate from a complexity perspective to not be able to use `json.dumps`.

My inclination is to write a class that stores the cached string and when the `default` handler encounters an instance of this class it uses the string without perform escaping. I have yet to figure out how to achieve this though, and I would be grateful for thoughts and assistance.

**EDIT** For clarity, here is an example of the proposed `default` technique:

```
class RawJSON(object):
   def __init__(self, str):
       self.str = str

class JSONEncoderWithRaw(json.JSONEncoder):
   def default(self, o):
       if isinstance(o, RawJSON): 
          return o.str # but avoid call to `encode_basestring` (or ASCII equiv.)
       return super(JSONEncoderWithRaw, self).default(o)
```

Here is a degenerate example of the above:

```
>>> class M():
       str = ''
>>> m = M()
>>> m.str = json.dumps(dict(x=123))
>>> json.dumps(dict(a=m), default=lambda (o): o.str)
'{"a": "{\\"x\\": 123}"}'
```

The desired output would include the unescaped string `m.str`, being:

```
'{"a": {"x": 123}}'
```

It would be good if the json module did not encode/escape the return of the `default` parameter, or if same could be avoided. In the absence of a method via the `default` parameter, one may have to achieve the objective here by overloading the `encode` and `iterencode` method of `JSONEncoder`, which brings challenges in terms of complexity, interoperability, and performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick-n-dirty way is to patch `json.encoder.encode_basestring*()` functions:

```
import json

class RawJson(unicode):
    pass

# patch json.encoder module
for name in ['encode_basestring', 'encode_basestring_ascii']:
    def encode(o, _encode=getattr(json.encoder, name)):
        return o if isinstance(o, RawJson) else _encode(o)
    setattr(json.encoder, name, encode)


print(json.dumps([1, RawJson(u'["abc", 2]'), u'["def", 3]']))
# -> [1, ["abc", 2], "[\"def\", 3]"]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are caching JSON strings, you need to first *decode* them to python structures; there is no way for `json.dumps()` to distinguish between normal strings and strings that are really JSON-encoded structures:

```
return json.dumps({'item1': json.loads(item1), 'item2': json.loads(item2), 'msg': "123"})
```

Unfortunately, there is no option to include already-converted JSON data in this; the `default` function is expected to return *Python* values. You extract data from whatever object that is passed in and return a value that *can* be converted to JSON, not a value that is already JSON itself.

The only other approach I can see is to insert "template" values, then use string replacement techniques to manipulate the JSON output to replace the templates with your actual cached data:

```
json_data = json.dumps({'item1': '==item1==', 'item2': '==item2==', 'msg': "123"})
return json_data.replace('"==item1=="', item1).replace('"==item2=="', item2)
```

A third option is to cache `item1` and `item2` in non-serialized form, as a Python structure instead of a JSON string.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I take it then that any type of return from the `default` parameter function shall be escaped? The answer wasn't obvious from my implementation (homebrew's Python 2.7 on Mac OS X), but I'd believe you if you say so. ;)

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: The `default` handler is only used for value types that  `json.dumps` doesn't know how to handle. `str` is easy, the module knows *exactly* how to handle it, so the `default` parameter is not consulted for those.

Comment: And 'escaping' isn't the correct term here; `json.dumps()` takes Python structures as input and produces JSON output. Give it a Python string and out comes a *JSON* string, regardless of what is inside of the Python string. You should not conflate the two types, even though JSON is byte data and *contained* in a Python string.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks. You'll see from the original question that I was contemplating passing a new type of class to `json.dumps` (not descended from `basestring`) and having the `default` handler return a string not escaped. The terminology in this context is "escape" or "encode" (see `python2.7/json/encoder.py:encode_basestring`). The problem seems to be either that something in `c_make_encoder` or `encode_basestring` in `encoder.py` escape the strings returned from `default`, which is the only place where we have access to the encoding mechanism (contra. `simplejson`'s `for_json`?).

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: Expanded; `default` is not the way to go, as it's return value is supposed to be more python structures, not JSON bytes.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: The new `for_json()` method support has the same semantics; the method must return a serializable object, a Python structure that can be serialized to JSON directly, not JSON bytes themselves.

Comment: Got it - very helpful, and a particularly insightful suggestion to use templates. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the better maintained `simplejson` instead of `json` which provides this functionality.

```
import simplejson as json
from simplejson.encoder import RawJSON

print(json.dumps([1, RawJSON(u'["abc", 2]'), u'["def", 3]']))
# -> [1, ["abc", 2], "[\"def\", 3]"]
```

You get simplicity of code, plus all the C optimisations of `simplejson`.